# adding init params to list in init(ServletConfig)

Tags: java, servlets

Trying to add init parameter names to a list in init(ServletConfig) method.

```
public void init(ServletConfig sc){
    try {
        super.init(sc);
        Enumeration<String> e= sc.getInitParameterNames();
        while(e.hasMoreElements()){
            list.add(e.nextElement());
        }
    } catch (ServletException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting a **NullPointerException** when I use this list because **e.hasMoreElement() returns false**.
I am pretty sure that I have added the init parameters correctly in the web.xml file.
What is going wrong? Please advice.

Comment: I think you are getting a NullPointerException because `list` is null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know the reason for the NullPointerException, my question is have I used the getInitParameters incorrectly such that e.hasMoreElements() returns false...

Comment: @NeloAngelo I don't think you understood that correctly: You probably get the NPE because `list` has not bee initialized (see Ramesh's answer below) - and not because you didn't add elements to it. BTW: How shall we tell if you used the init parameters correctly if you don't post the code where you set them?

Comment: It is possible that hasMoreElements returns false the first time. Are you sure you have init parameters?

Comment: I think  sc.getInitParameterNames() is null, check your init params

Comment: Yup, ramesh's answer was of great help. I was not initialing the list beforehand. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have not `intialized` the `list` object. The `list` object is null.

Change the code list this:

```
public void init(ServletConfig sc){
   try {
      super.init(sc);
      list = new ArrrayList<String>();
      Enumeration<String> e= sc.getInitParameterNames();
      while(e.hasMoreElements()){
         list.add(e.nextElement());
      }
   } catch (ServletException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have one more question. As I read from Head First Servlets that when we override init(ServletConfig) we must a call to super.init(ServletConfig). Is it true?
And if it is then I have a little confusion coz my code wasn't generating any errors or exception without the call to super.init(ServletConfig)

Comment: super.init(ServletConfig) only initializes the servlet config member variable. And, you should face the problem only if you use getServletConfig() method which return the intialized method.